# JQuery Check if Div html has a certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check with JQuery if a Div #id has a certain character or not.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
if ($("#mydiv").html('0')) {

  alert'zero character was found';

}
```

The alert is not popping up.

I'm I doing it wrong?

Comment: Your title says check div HTML but your question says div ID. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($("#mydiv:contains(0)")) {

  alert('zero character was found'); // do not forget also `(`

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try using [**`contains`**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$("#mydiv:contains(0)")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly and you're looking for a div whose ***id*** contains the string `0` then this should work for you:

```
 if ($("div[id*='0']").length>0) {
     alert('zero character was found');
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mT862/

Answer (score 0):

try using native javascript

```
var str = $("#mydiv").text();
if (str.indexOf('0') !== -1) {
  alert('zero character was found');
}
```